# is there a way to get 'numpy.linalg.svd()' code

Tags: python

Since numpy.linalg.svd() is a predefined function i didn't find the inner code of it.

```
from scipy import linalg

u, s, v = np.linalg.svd(b, full_matrices=True)
```

Comment: The source code is at https://github.com/scipy/scipy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import inspect
from scipy import linalg
import numpy as np
print(inspect.getsource(np.linalg.svd))
```